# Prime Faces editing component and Selenium

Tags: webdriver, selenium2

I'm creating a new tests with selenium in my job. But i can't get one element in my system.
We use Prime Faces and i can't get this [element](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/editor.jsf). I need to send a value to him, and He is a iFrame.

I tried to use Selenium IDE but i had no success.
When I try to get the xPath, i get `/htm/body` :(
Someone know how i can get the full path of this element?

I'm using Selenium Web Driver.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a little searching, I found this solution

```
driver.switchTo().frame(find(By.id("id_frame")));
find(By.xpath("/html/body")).click();

WebElement editable = driver.switchTo().activeElement(); 

editable.clear();
editable.sendKeys("Your text here"); 

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
find(By.xpath("btn_save")).click();
```

worked very well